# API Management with GIT

Tags: git, azure-api-management, ibm-api-management

I have an API management instance running. 
I know API management has its own GIT repository.

I can successfully clone, change and push changes up to my API management GIT repository.

My issue is, I have my own VSTS Git Repository (source control for all my other code) that I need to keep using. The fact that I now have 2 GIT repositories (one in VSTS and one in API management) is confusing.

Can someone let me know what the process for managing these two repositories is? Or is there a way to use only mine and not use API management's GIT repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would like to merge `API management` into `VSTG`:

- `cd path/to/VSTG-repo`
- `git remote add API-management path/to/VSTG-repo`
- `git fetch API-management`
- `git merge API-management/master` # or whichever branch you want to merge
- `git remote remove API-management`