# API Management with GIT and Octopus - Git PUSH / Git PULL

Tags: octopus-deploy, azure-api-management, ibm-api-management

Following on from this post of mine:

[API Management with GIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38496012/api-management-with-git)

I have an API management instance running. I know API management has its own GIT repository.

I can successfully clone, change and push changes up to my API management GIT repository.

I am also running Octopus deploy and am trying to use this:

[Git Push](https://library.octopusdeploy.com/step-template/actiontemplate-git-pull-(https))

and this:

[Git Pull](https://library.octopusdeploy.com/step-template/actiontemplate-git-pull-(https))

To pull my code from my companies GIT repository and push to the APIM GIT repository.

The thing is, these to plugins fail immediately with an issue not being able to find file paths on the Octopus server. Also, these were written in 2014.

Is there a recommended better way to pull from your companies repo and push to APIM repository? Also, if I am pulling to Octopus, where does the code get stored before it is pushed to APIM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I think this plug in is out of date. I ended up writing my own PowerShell GIT bash and it works a treat.

I get the APIM json code from my companies source control then push it ti the APIM GIT repository and publish it using PowerShell.

Comment: Is it possible for you to post or share this PowerShell? I'm about to start a similar task, and would really appreciate a good starting point. Thanks!

Comment: Give me a couple of hours to find it

Comment: Ping me your email

Comment: Sent. Let me know if you don't get it as it has 1 attachment.

Comment: Got it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has this issue in the future.
The cause is most likely you are trying to use the GitPull step from the octopus server, while the code behind the step makes reference to this parameter `$OctopusParameters['Octopus.Tentacle.Agent.ApplicationDirectoryPath']`.

[image: Running Step from Octopus Server]

This parameter seems to return an empty value. *I have not tried running from a Deployment Target*.

The git clone directory could be another parameter/variable specified
I am raising this with the Octopus team.